# Adding of more colors in QR Code encoding algorithm

Tags: c#, qr-code

I like to  four  colors in generation of QR Code and decode it properly. Any idea to change the generation algorithm in C sharp for proper encoding with more colors.

Comment: You mean generate the individual squares in one of four colours to encode extra data? (Four including white, or do you mean five states?) What kind of suggestions are you after?

Comment: Yes, I like to generate the individual squares to encode extra data , four including white . I like to add color in the encoding area , leaving the standard formatting area as same color as standard QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to simply generate a QR code in colors that are not black and white? That's easy. Use dark colors instead of black, and light color instead of white. You would just need to change the RGB value used by the generator. That requires modifying the source code, usually

If you mean that you want to modify the QR code generator to encode data by means of color, well, you can do that, but it will be a new format and not a QR code anymore.

Comment: I wish to generate qr code with more colors .So, that the data capacity increases.If, I use 4 colors the capacity is increased by twice. I have a problem in bits placement. In standard qr code 1 bit was stored in 1 module . Now, I have to place two bits in a module. Please suggest me some possible solutions for placing the bits in a module .Thanks..

Comment: You are inventing a new format -- you can do whatever you want, and I can't tell you how your format works. You should first understand how the QR code format works by reading the ISO spec. Of course, the QR codes you generate will not be QR codes at all, and will not be readable by any reader software.

Comment: As,  you said it won't be readable by any reader software, I have to make change in the decoder application too. I have read the ISO spec.The original patterns like position detection , timing , alignment will remain same . In the masking technique there will be 2 bits reversal instead of 1 . I am working with zxing c sharp code.Thank you for the answer .

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to what [Microsoft Tag](http://tag.microsoft.com/home.aspx) used to do.  It's dead now, but maybe it will spark some ideas for someone's new format

[image: tag]

```
private void CreateTag()
{
    try
    {
        MIBPContractClient OMIBPClient = new MIBPContractClient();
        UserCredential oCredential = new UserCredential();
        oCredential.AccessToken = "Enter your access token";         
        URITag uriTag = new URITag();
        uriTag.Title = "My Tag Title";
        uriTag.MedFiUrl = "http://www.something.com";
        uriTag.UTCStartDate = new DateTime(yyyy, mm, dd);
        uriTag.UTCEndDate = new DateTime(yyyy, mm, dd);
        uriTag.PublicTitle = "My Tag Public Title";
        OMIBPClient.CreateTag(oCredential, "Main", uriTag);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```